# boldsymbol badly modifies spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, symbols, amsmath, bold

In the example below, it is my feeling that `\boldsymbol` badly increases the horizontal spacing with the index:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\sigma}_0$ $\sigma_0$
\end{document}
```

Shouldn't this be corrected?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Load the `bm` package and the problem goes away, both using `\bm` and `\boldsymbol` (which gets redefined by `bm` to be the same as `\bm`).

This spacing issue is one of the reasons why `\bm` should be used for bolding math instead of `amsmath`'s `\boldsymbol`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\boldsymbol{\sigma}_0&\\
\bm{\sigma}_0&\\
\sigma_0&
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The difference can be seen with the following example

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\amsboldsymbol\boldsymbol
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
\verb|amsmath's \boldsymbol| & $\amsboldsymbol{\sigma}_0$ \\
\verb|\bm| & $\bm{\sigma}_0$ \\
 & $\sigma_0$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you note, if `bm` and `amsmath` are both loaded, there's no difference in the outputs of `\boldsymbol{\sigma}` and `\bm{\sigma}`. The recommendation should thus focus on always loading the `bm` package, rather than on preferring `\bm` over `\boldsymbol`, right?

Comment: @Mico In fact. `bm` does `\let\boldsymbol\bm`.

Comment: in fact, the documentation for `amsmath` recommends `bm`, although not as strongly as it might.  (on the list for improvement.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a minor increase in the symbol width. Here is a correction using an `\ooalign` overlay:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\boldsigma}{{\ooalign{\phantom{$\sigma$}\cr\hidewidth$\boldsymbol{\sigma}$\hidewidth}}}
\begin{document}

$\boldsymbol{\sigma}_0$ $\sigma_0$

Width of $\boldsymbol{\sigma}$: \savebox9{$\boldsymbol{\sigma}$}\the\wd9\par
Width of $\sigma$: \savebox9{$\sigma$}\the\wd9\par
Width of $\boldsigma$: \savebox9{$\boldsigma$}\the\wd9

$\boldsigma_0$ $\sigma_0$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your construction succeeds in making `\boldsigma` as wide as `\sigma`. However, `\boldsigma_0` is about `0.36pt` *wider* than `\sigma_0`.

Comment: the problem isn't the width of the symbol but \boldsymbol makes an hbox so you lose the inter letter kerns that normally adjust subscript position and the subscript is placed after the box not tucked in to the italic letter.